# Update numpy at each index based on the previous index

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a vectorized way of updating each arbitrary index in a numpy array based on the indices before it? For example, in pseudo code, if I have the matrix

```
1 2 3
3 1 4
1 3 2
```

And for every index (i, j), i want to do:

```
m[i,j] += max(m[i, j-1], m[i-1, j])
```

Now I know I can do this iteratively, but I want to know if there's a vectorized way to do this, since it would be more efficient than taking it out of the numpy data space over and over again.

Also, I know this is a fence posting problem, since m[0, 0] doesn't have a previous element. This is easily fixed by prepending an extra row and column of 0's to the matrix.

Comment: consider using `numba`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way you could vectorize it:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[3, 1, 4],[1, 3, 2]])

arr_A = np.roll(arr, 1, axis=0)
arr_B = np.roll(arr, 1, axis=1)

max_val = np.maximum(arr_A, arr_B)

output = arr + max_val
>>> [[4 5 5]
     [7 4 7]
     [4 4 6]]
```

Note that this gives a different answer to your code above because the way you have it written means the values are updated after every loop. If you want that, then you are tied to using the `for` loops.

```
>>> [[ 4  6  9] # Output after updating the matrix in each loop.
     [ 7  8 13]
     [ 8 11 15]]
```

If you are looking for a similar kind of algorithm rather than trying to recover this exact output then `np.roll()` should work to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to created shifted versions of the matrix:

```
m += np.maximum(np.roll(m, 1, axis=0), np.roll(m, 1, axis=1))
```

This creates two new copies though. Zero padding is required because roll re-introduces elements that "rolled" beyond the boundary:

```
p = np.pad(m, [(1, 1), (1, 1)], 'constant')
m += np.maximum(np.roll(p, 1, axis=0), np.roll(p, 1, axis=1))[1:-1, 1:-1]
```